# Import jest object when not using jest runner

Tags: jestjs

What do I need to import/require in order to access the magic [`jest` object](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/jest-object.html) that contains `jest.fn` when not running my code with jest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jest now exports the `jest-mock` package seperately (https://github.com/facebook/jest/tree/master/packages/jest-mock).

```
import jestMock from 'jest-mock';
const mockFunction = jestMock.fn();
```